# 'error unrecognized service' when trying to test cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to follow the instructions on Cloudera's website here [1] to
set up a test cluster in pseudo distributed mode. But I am unable to even
start any services after formatting the namenode

```
$ for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done 
error unrecognized service
```

Comment: Where's here? O.o

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can simply run the different commands separately.

```
$ cd /etc/init.d
$ ls hadoop-hdfs-*
```

You will see there are three files. You can start the daemons using the following commands:

```
$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode start
$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode start
```

Done!!!!